# Is it proper to use images inside header tags?

Tags: html, seo

I've done quite a bit of googling on this, but I haven't been able to get a straight answer.

In terms of SEO, how bad is it to use images for your headings?  The reason for doing this of course would be to be able to display non-standard fonts.  I know it is bad to use images in place of headings, but I'm wondering if this sort of syntax would do anything to make it more search engine friendly:

`<h1><img src="heading.jpg" alt="Level 1 Heading" /></h1>`

Does it have the same effect as this?:

`<h1>Level 1 Heading</h1>`

I suspect the answer to this is no.  I think search engines probably wouldn't like this because you could put any text in the alt attribute without it actually being displayed on the page.  So in that case, what is the best way to use images for headings without sacrificing SEO?

Comment: Not recommendable, because crawlers can't interpret images, but they can text...so it's not wise SEO, yet valid I guess.

Answer (score 8):

One old trick is to put the real text in the `<h1>` box, but then use CSS to make the text invisible and put your image in the background.

So you'd do something like:

```
h1 {
  color: transparent;
  background-image: url(your/cool/image.png);
  width:400px; height: 300px;
}
```

Astute Stackoverflow member [K Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/374804/k-ivanov) points out that it would probably be better to make the text invisible by positioning it way off the page with "text-indent: -5000px" or something.

Comment: to make invisible in a sense use something like text-indent: -1000px; or absolute positioning of the text otherwise screen readers will not pick it up as well, unless you don't care about being Section 508-compliant

Comment: @K Ivanov that's a really good point!!  Thanks I'll update the answer.

Comment: We should not hide the h1 tag or make the h1 tag invisible to user by making the color same as background color, or taking it out of view part. This will be detected by google crawler and penalized

Comment: @anandharshan that may be a consideration for many people, but not everybody. Secured web applications, for example, are never accessed by search engines.

Answer (score 6):

It is a recognised practise (neither good nor bad) to use `text-indent:-9999px;` alongside `overflow:hidden;` for headings.

This offsets the text by a massive amount then uses the overflow to hide it.

That means you can have a nice big description/title in your `<header>` and have an image with the description/title the way you want it to appear, that way you get the best of both worlds.

A perfect example of this is: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design-blog/

The "LatestWord" section is an image, but if you look at the CSS for the section you will see this technique employed.

Comment: The technique is called ["CSS Image Replacement"](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+image+replacement) in general and there's a relatively recent (okay, 3 year old) [overview of pros and cons of various approaches here](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/).

Comment: We should not hide the h1 tag or make the h1 tag invisible to user by making the color same as background color, or taking it out of view part. This will be detected by google crawler and penalized

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution to the problem of non-standard fonts in headers would be to use the [Google Fonts API](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/), assuming that the fonts that they have available fulfill your needs.

You could also take a look at the stylesheets they generate and attempt generating them yourself (assuming that you need to).